# C++ Strange situation with, e.g. applying an existing variable to new variable

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++, variables, pointers

Well, today; I've come across a strange little situation with e.g. `char* cFileCopy = strDrive;` _

This should make `cFileCopy` hold the value of `strDrive` only at this point, which it does, however when I use `strcat(cFileCopy, cFileName);`

the value of `strDrive` also changes to the value of `cFileCopy` after `strcat()`

_

I'm not sure what's happening, but here's the code if anybody could shed a little light on the situation.

```
DWORD dwDrives = GetLogicalDrives();
char strDrive[3];

for(int i = 0; i<26; i++)
{
    wsprintf(strDrive, "%c:\\", 'A'+i);
    if(GetDriveType(strDrive) == DRIVE_REMOVABLE)
    {
        char* cFileName = new char[11];
        cFileName = "test.txt";
        char* cFileCopy = strDrive;
        strcat(cFileCopy, cFileName);
        MessageBox(NULL, strDrive, "Strange", MB_OK); //MSG - This shows drive:\test.txt when it should show only drive:\/
        MessageBox(NULL, cFileCopy, "OK", MB_OK); //MSG - This should be showing drive:\test.txt, which it does.
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: Since this is C++ use `std::string` then you will get the behaviour you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to revisit how pointers work - if you point two variables to the same memory (as here), then a modification to the memory pointed to by one will also change the value pointedd to by the other.

Note that you are also overflowing the 3 byte `strDrive` buffer handily in that `strcat` call, which will result in obscure bugs surfacing down the line.  There is also a leak of `cFileName` which has no `delete[]` call to match the `new[]` (use smart pointers or `std::string` instead to simplify this).

If you want the semantics you expect, you should be using C++ `std::string`, not raw pointers.

Comment: Ah, that's shed some light upon my situation, Thank you; - 

I'm used to coding in PHP where you are able to do such as `$foo=""; $bar="D:\"; $foo=$bar;` 

Thank you again, I will revisit on how pointers work, an will see about using `std::string`.

Comment: Yes, C is less forgiving re memory management.  C++ offers smart pointers and other tools to assist with this.

Answer (score 0):

An array variable such as strDrive[3] actually stores a pointer to the first value (strDrive[0]). Using [n] offsets that address to a specific index of the array and dereferences it, in this case getting you the nth character.

When you do char* cFileCopy = strDrive; your are copying the address stored in strDrive to the variable cFileCopy. The two now point to the same memroy, so logically when you alter the value poitned to by cFileCopy, you alter the value pointed to by strDrive. If you mouseover the two variables while debugging, you will likely see that they have the same value displayed (an address in Hex). As Steve said, a better udnerstanding of pointers is what you need.

You could achieve what you want with strcpy, but it's never going to be pretty.

Comment: Arrays are not a pointer to the first value, they simply decay into one due to language features. There is additional data that an array variable uses but pointers do not have.

Comment: @peachykeen Do you have a reference for what this additional data is? I'm curious. Come to think of it you can use sizeof() on such variables, so I guess that's part of it.

Comment: The data is compiler, or even memory-manager, dependent. Typically it's stored in a few bytes before the address given by the malloc/new call, and includes at least the size of the allocated chunk (which is why `sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0])` == the number of elements).

Answer (score 0):

The `cFileCopy` is only a pointer with no own memory space, it references to the memory of `strDrive` .
Correctly it should be create space to it with new or malloc and then copy the string strDrive with strcpy function.
So use

```
char* cFileCopy = new char[15];
strcpy(cFileCopy,strDrive);
strcat(cFileCopy, cFileName);
delete[] cFileCopy;
```

In this case strDrive will not be changed. Do not forget, to free memory on the end.